# countifs named range gives #VALUE error

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I just replaced the values within a formula and now it's value errors all the way, I'm not sure why:

old formula: `=COUNTIFS(Cat,M$3,Sup,$B45)`

new formula: `=COUNTIFS(Cat,M$3,Client,$B45)`

simply doing `=COUNTIFS(Cat,M$3)` and `=COUNTIFS(Client,$B45)` works, but I obviously need the common count of the two!

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Cat,M$3,Client,$B45))` also gives `#value` error

The named ranges work, so what is the problem?

Comment: one problem may be that Cat and Client are not the same size.

Comment: Amazing, the ranges were not identical in my old formula either (one was A:A the other was specific like A1:A1000) and yet they worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ScottCraner Going to make that an answer?

Comment: @Chrismas007 I see this more a typo. So as I see it, it is more a comment worthy question.  Feel free if you want to wax eloquent on the proper use of ranges in COUNTIFS().

Comment: @ScottCraner I VTC'd for typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution lies in making sure that the two ranges are of same length, as mentioned in the comment.

I'm hoping to mark this as complete, since voting to close did not work out, but this question has been resolved.